# Get query param on register

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created an observer on `customer_register_success`. I want to use some predefined urls to register customers e.g `customer/account/create/?testparam=12345` and I want to get that query param inside the observer I've created. Obviously `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('testparam');` doesn't work in this case. How could I do that?

Comment: what is the meaning of that parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value using this code.

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('testparam');
```

Answer (score 0):

To get Request parameters in the Observer, use following code

> `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();`

To get post variable

> `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('testparam');`

Answer (score 0):

Might you have to use customer/account/createpost/ to set your query parameter.
To get post data at time of customer_register_success.